# Syncing software with 2 way sync and no deletions

Tags: windows, file-synchronization

So I am looking for a syncing software for syncing my computer pictures with my NAS. The software should:

- Be free
- No file transfer limit
- Have an option for 2 way sync with no deletions made on both side
- Work with Windows

I am currently using Sync Toy but there is only one way without deletions, not two way.

Comment: The free version of [SyncBack](https://www.2brightsparks.com/) might do the trick.  If you try it, let us know if it works for you.

Comment: It work! Thank you so much! I'm surprised a free software as that much features.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad it worked for your needs.  I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free version of [SyncBack](https://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/index.html) (known as SyncBackFree) by [2BrightSparks](https://www.2brightsparks.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=9641) meets your requirements:

- Be free - ***YES!***
- No file transfer limit - ***YOU BETCHA!***
- Have an option for 2 way sync with no deletions made on both side - ***ABSOLUTELY!***
- Work with Windows - ***WITHOUT A DOUBT!***

SyncBack is stable and is actively developed to add features and fix bugs.

As a bonus, the developers offer a free portable version, [offered here](https://www.2brightsparks.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=9641).

Answer (score 0):

[FreeFileSync](http://www.freefilesync.org/) would also fit your requirements and can also sync your files cross-platform (Windows-Linux-Mac).

You get to choose whether to delete files or not as well as what to do in case of conflicts.

You can also set it up to run in background if you'd like.

FFS looks for changes based on timestamp and size or based on content, at your election (the first is obviously faster while the latter is more precise).

It is free, frequently updated and improved and is quick to the task.